# Linking Php help Into Netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans

Im new to netbeans, before this i use Nusphere Php

Is there a way i can mimick feature in nusphere that allow me to open up php manual help file (not an online manual) when i highlight on any php function and then press f1

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click at the beginning or on any part of any function and then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd>

Comment: if i not mistaken ctrl + space is for auto completion, when i pres ctrl + space it open help manual and auto completion too, is there a way to open just the help manual? Btw i guess i cant simply link php manul to netbeans right

Comment: @slier: Yes, it is for autocomplete, which will also give you the docs if you rollover the specific function. I don't know what you mean by link PHP manual to NetBeans, when it is already there! :)

Comment: in NuspherePhp u can link downloadable php manual to the ide itself..so when i highlight a function and then press f1, it will open the downloadable php manual and search the function that i had highlight..so i guess NB not capable to do that..its a handy feature when i dont have internet connection

Answer (score 0):

If you hover the cursor over the function and hold Control, then slightly move the mouse (still on the function name), it will pop up a dialog window with information about the function.  If the function doesn't have too much documentation, you will see the link to the php manual, but unfortunately the dialog does not scroll so for more complex functions you won't be able to see this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i think what you are searching is `Ctrl + Space`.

It opens up a window with some helping info